# Validation Error when insert new data using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to insert new data into a collection, but when I submit the form, I get a validation error.

> ValidationError: Teacher validation failed: subject: Please enter subject, second_subject: Path `second_subject` is required.

**HTML File**

```
<form action="/register" method="post" id="form3">
    <div class="form-group"><label class="small mb-1">Full name</label><input class="form-control py-4" style="width: 50%;" type="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter full name" /></div>
    <div class="form-group"><label class="small mb-1" >Email</label><input class="form-control py-4" style="width: 50%;" type="username"  name="username" placeholder="Enter email address" /></div>
    <div class="form-group"><label class="small mb-1" >Password</label><input class="form-control py-4" style="width: 50%;" type="password"  name="password" placeholder="Password" /></div>
    <input type="hidden" id="roles" name="roles" value="Creator">
    <div class="form-group"><label class="small mb-1" >Select Primary Subject</label>
        <select name="subject" class="form-control" style="width: 30%;" id="subject">
            <option value="">-- Select Subject --</option>
            <% subject.forEach(function (subject) { %>
            <option value= "" ><%= subject.subject_name %></option>
            <% }) %>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group"><label class="small mb-1" >Select Secondary Subject</label>
        <select name="secondary_subject" class="form-control" style="width: 30%;" id="secondary_subject">
            <option value="">-- Select Subject --</option>
            <% subject.forEach(function (subject) { %>
            <option value= "" ><%= subject.subject_name %></option>
            <% }) %>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group"><label class="small mb-1" >Preferred Level of study</label>
        <select name="level" class="form-control" style="width: 30%;" id="level">
            <option value="">-- Select level --</option>
            <option value="Level 1">Level 1</option>
            <option value="Level 2">Level 2</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group mt-4 mb-0"><input type="submit" value="Submit" style="width: 20%;" a class="btn btn-primary btn-block" href="/admin_user"></div>           
</form>
```

**Route**

```
if(req.body.subject && req.body.secondary_subject,req.body.level){
    var teacherData = {
        subject: req.body.subject,
        second_subject: req.body.secondary_subject,
        level: req.body.level,
        userId:req.session.userId,
    }
    Teacher.create(teacherData, function (err, teacher){
        if(err){
            return next(err)
        }else
        {
            console.log('Teacher details added'+teacher)
            return res.redirect('/admin_user');
        }
    });
}else{
    var err = new Error('All fields have to be filled out');
    err.status = 400;
    return next(err);
}
```

**Schema**

```
var TeacherSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({

    subject: {
        type:String,
        required:true,
    },

    level: {
        type:String,
        required:true,
    },


    second_subject: {
        type:String,
        required:true,
    },

    userId:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
    },

});
```

Comment: Do you really send secondary_subject in req.body? Can you check by console.log(req.body)?

Comment: this is result

{
  name: 'dsad',
  username: 'sadsad',
  password: 'sdas',
  roles: 'Creator',
  subject: '',
  secondary_subject: '',
  level: 'Level 1'
}

Comment: So you send empty seconday_subject, that's why you get the validation error. Check if you are really choosing some value in the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your **Route** file, check for both "not null" and "not equal to empty string". This would ensure that empty strings are not entered to your database.

```js
if (req.body.subject != null && req.body.subject !== "" && req.body.secondary_subject != null && req.body.secondary_subject !== "" && req.body.level != null && req.body.level !== "") {
  var teacherData = {
    subject: req.body.subject,
    second_subject: req.body.secondary_subject,
    level: req.body.level,
    userId: req.session.userId,
  }
  Teacher.create(teacherData, function(err, teacher) {
    if (err) {
      return next(err)
    } else {
      console.log('Teacher details added' + teacher)
      return res.redirect('/admin_user');
    }
  });
} else {
  var err = new Error('All fields have to be filled out');
  err.status = 400;
  return next(err);
}
```